# Hide navigation bar in UINavigationViewController's root view, but show it in others

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am a beginner in iOS development, and the title pretty much says it.

I have a UINavigationController; I'd like it not to show the navigation bar if the user is looking at the root view, but show the navigation bar in other views.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this line of code on all your view controllers `[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];` If no animation is needed you can do `animated:NO` and add this code in `viewDidLoad` otherwise put it `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Yes I knew about this, I was just wondering if there's perhaps a per-view way to set whether the navigation bar appears. I'll accept this for now though, thanks.

Comment: That is the case if you say [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; on your rootViewController, and [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]; on your other viewControllers, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah I guess in the end it has the same effect, it's just that it changes the property each time you switch views... nevermind though this works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

In the Storyboard, select the root view (outlined in blue), then go to the properties editor (the one on the right), show **Attributes** and one of the options should be to hide it (default is **Inferred**).

Comment: This only modifies the view frames in interface builder. It doesn't actually show/hide the navigation bar, in iOS 6 at least.

Comment: This is true as early as I can remember.  All the bar stuff is just there for you to size your views according to different bar states.